# How do I read headers from a QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, http

How can one read headers for example a cookie out of a QNetworkReply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consulting [the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html), there are a few methods related to reading headers: header, rawHeader, rawHeaderList, and rawHeaderPairs. For the specific case of getting a cookie, you can use the header method. It would look something like this:

```
QNetworkReply *reply;
// somehow give reply a value
QVariant cookieVar = reply.header(QNetworkRequest::CookieHeader);
if (cookieVar.isValid()) {
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = cookieVar.value<QList<QNetworkCookie> >();
    foreach (QNetworkCookie cookie, cookies) {
        // do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

The header method only works for certain HTTP headers, though. In the general case, if there is no QNetworkRequest::KnownHeaders value for the header you want, the rawHeader method is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

I just thought to add to the above answer concerning rawHeader

```
QList<QByteArray> headerList = reply->rawHeaderList();
foreach(QByteArray head, headerList) {
    qDebug() << head << ":" << reply->rawHeader(head);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the answer of Evan Shaw, but there is a little mistake.
The  QNetworkRequest::CookieHeader need change to QNetworkRequest::SetCookieHeader. Because I found it is Set-Cookie in the header of QNetworkReply other than Cookie.

```
QNetworkReply *reply;
// somehow give reply a value
QVariant cookieVar = reply.header(QNetworkRequest::SetCookieHeader);
if (cookieVar.isValid()) {
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = cookieVar.value<QList<QNetworkCookie> >();
    foreach (QNetworkCookie cookie, cookies) {
        // do whatever you want here
    }
}
```